# kill -9 -1 as root shut down the server?

Tags: linux, centos-6

I have issue the command `kill -9 -1` as root and right now I can't connect any more to the server. I get Connection Refused. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: push the power button

Comment: Oh boy that means I need to contact the web host :((. Thanks for this.